# Editing users info with struct

Tags: c#

```
struct person
{
    public int id;
    public long phone;
    public string name, family, add;
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", id, name, family, phone, add);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static List<person> info = new List<person>();
    static void Edit()
    {
        Display();
        Console.Write("Choose your target ID:");
        int ed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < info.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ed == info[i].id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1.ID\n2.Name\n3.FamilyName\n4.PhoneNumber\n5.Address\n6.Exit to menu");
                Console.WriteLine("Which part of the user info would you like to update:");
                int ed1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                bool exm = false;
                while (true)
                {
                    switch (ed1)
                    {
                        case 1:

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.Write("Enter Your Name:");
                            info[i].name = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.Write("Enter Your FamilyName:");
                            info[i].family = Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.Write("Enter Your Name:");
                            info[i].phone = Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine());
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Console.Write("Enter Your Name:");
                            info[i].add =Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (exm == true)
                                Main();
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operation");
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to make a program that gets users info then shows them what they can do. The program methods include input, display, search, remove, edit, all work fine but edit. I don't know how to make it work.

For edit I'm gonna get user id, then let him choose which part of that id he wants to change. In all cases I tried to replace new info but it shows me an error on info[i].would you help me to do this in this way?

Comment: Why do you want to use a struct and not a class?

Comment: i get it its easier if i use the class but its a kind of homework and i have to do it thsis way

Comment: What error/exception are you getting and on what line ? there is no point hiding it from us, it contains important information

Comment: CS1612:cannot modify the return value of 'List<person>,this[int]' because it is not a variable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a property of a struct stored in a list; either change your `struct` to a `class` and you will then be able to modify individual properties, or change your editing routine so that it either

- creates a whole new Person struct using all the data from the existing person struct with the new bit of data you want to change, and replace the old person struct in the list with the new one you've made or
- gets the person out of the list into a temporary variable, changes the name, puts the temp variable back into the list

As an academic exercise I suppose it's teaching you about value types but it's a bit abstruse; perhaps your teacher is hoping you will pick up on the fact that accessing `list[x]` creates a copy of what is in the list at x. As there is no point editing a copy (and then throwing the copy away, as a direct edit would do) the compiler warns you that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because structs are `value type`.
When you do `info[i]` it returns value of the element at `i` rather than the reference to it. Modifying this value by calling setter doesn't change anything in the actual struct instance. Hence the error.
A naive workaround would be

```cs
 info[i]=new person{name= Console.ReadLine()};
```

If not for an assignment, you should definetely use classes in these cases